# Why UITextView.contentSize.height doesn't work if it's not editable or scrollEnabled in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitextview

I have a UITextView like so:

```
var textView = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,20))
textView.scrollEnabled = true
textView.editable = true
self.view.addSubview(textView)
```

Nothing weird there

Then I want to update the text:

```
textView.text = "some short text"
```

If I request the .contentSize.height for it I get `20` which is correct
If the text is longer and has more lines:

```
textView.text = "some longer text\n another line\n one more line"
```

And get the height again I get `75` which is also correct.

But as soon as I make it not editable and not scrollable it fails and always returns `20`

```
textView.scrollEnabled = false
textView.editable = false
textView.text = "some short text"
print(textView.contentSize.height) //prints 20
textView.text = "some longer text\n another line\n one more line"
print(textView.contentSize.height) //prints 20
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you can disable scroll then you set `contentSize.height` equal to `view.height`.

In second i don't know reason its behavior, but if you modify your code like:

```
textView.editable = true
textView.text = "some short text"
print(textView.contentSize.height) //prints 20
textView.text = "some longer text\n another line\n one more line"
print(textView.contentSize.height) //prints 20
extView.editable = false
```

you get right content height. I think so - then you set editable to false, you also disable some option who will change content size

Comment: If disable scrollable, contentSize is the same with frame.size.

Comment: @BollMose you are right. Setting `isScrollEnabled` to false on `UITextView returns  the size of it's frame.

Comment: Setting isScrollEnabled at layoutsubviews  (not viewdidload) will give the right contentsize